# Regexp replacement features

Tags: evil, regular-expressions, replace

In the replacement part of `:s` in `evil` I can add commands like `\l` to lowercase the next char and `\L` to lowercase everything that follows, but I am unable to find documentation for that anywhere.
I would have expected it to be documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html but that only talks about matching, not replacing.

What I found however, is that its support seems to match this list: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/perl_format.html

Is there documentation on this?

Answer (score 1):

When searching for replacement features of `evil`, I often start with a search related to `Vim`. For example, the `\l` and `\L` `evil` syntaxes definitely have something to do with the `Vim` ones (see [Changing case with regular expressions](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Changing_case_with_regular_expressions)) as [`evil` tries to emulate the main features of `Vim`](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil).

Comment: so evil has no own documentation on this I guess?